# How to crop an image in Julia?

Tags: julia

I current have some images which contain a border that I need to remove so that I can use those images for a computer vision ML project. How can I use Julia to crop the images and remove the border?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried? Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Julia, you can do the following:

```
using Images

img_source = testimage("lighthouse")
# where testimage is function from the `TestImages` package.

# You can then do the following:
new_img = img_source[100:200, 100:200]
```

where `img_source[y1:y2, x1:x2]` represents the coordinates of the subsection of the original image you want to use. You can read more about this in the [Julia Images docs](https://juliaimages.org/latest/examples/spatial_transformation/SpatialTransformations/#Cropping-Operation).